# Monogame Pipeline Tool Error

Tags: monogame

Build error while I was trying to build an image of a lion:

[image: Error]

So I was trying to build an image through the monogame content pipeline tool in Visual Studio 2017 community, but when I click build, it says "Build: 0 succeeded,1 failed, time elapsed" then it says how many seconds it took etc,etc. But when I try to build an image on a school computer in my computer programming class at school, it works fine.

I really want to know how to get it to work because I have never messed the program files or anything and I have never used monogame content pipeline tool at home, my class barely started using it and I know how to use it but it doesn't work. I tried to uninstall VS and the Monogame SDK and reinstall them, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

From the image you provided it looks like the root of the problem is loading the FreeImage.dll. Looking around the MonoGame forums I found someone with a similar problem: http://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-noob-unable-to-load-freeimage/6255. The post is from Aug 2015, that dependency was last updated in Jul 2015, and so it should still apply to the problem you're having.

The problem appears rooted in a dependency FreeImage.dll has on the VC++ 2012 runtime. If you do not have installed on your computer you will not be able to load the native .DLL required to process the image. The re-distributable may be downloaded and installe from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-Us/download/details.aspx?id=30679. Assuming the dependency hasn't changed (unlikely for reasons noted in the previous paragraph) this should resolve your issue.